# Most efficient way of testing a value is in a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe that I have from a csv which I am testing various aspects of. These all seem to go along the lines of either is this column like this regex or is this column in this list.

So I have the dataframe a bit like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.DataFrame({'full_name': ['Mickey Mouse', 'M Mouse', 'Mickey RudeWord Mouse'], 'nationality': ['Mouseland', 'United States', 'Canada']})
```

I am generating new columns based on that content like so:

```
def full_name_metrics(full_name):
    lst_rude_words = ['RUDEWORD', 'ANOTHERRUDEWORD', 'YOUGETTHEIDEA']
    # metric of whether full name has less than two distinct elements
    full_name_less_than_2_parts = len(full_name.split(' '))<2
    # metric of whether full_name contains an initial
    full_name_with_initial = 1 in [len(x) for x in full_name.split(' ')]
    # metric of whether name matches an offensive word
    full_name_with_offensive_word = any(item in full_name.upper().split(' ') for item in lst_rude_words)
    return pd.Series([full_name_less_than_2_parts, full_name_with_initial, full_name_with_offensive_word])

df[['full_name_less_than_2_parts', 'full_name_with_initial', 'full_name_with_offensive_word']] = df.apply(lambda x: full_name_metrics(x['full_name']), axis=1)
```

|  | full_name | nationality | full_name_less_than_2_parts | full_name_with_initial | full_name_with_offensive_word |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mickey Mouse | Mouseland | False | False | False |
| 1 | M Mouse | United States | False | True | False |
| 2 | Mickey RudeWord Mouse | Canada | False | False | True |

It works but for 25k records and more of these types of controls its taking more time than I'd like.

So is there a better way? Am I better off having the rude word list as another dataframe or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the list checking that you want to speed up - then probably the `Series.str.contains` method can help -

```
lst_rude_words_as_str = '|'.join(lst_rude_words)
df['full_name_with_offensive_word'] = df['full_name'].str.upper().str.contains(lst_rude_words_as_str, regex=True)
```

Here's how the `%timeit` looks for me:

```
def func_in_list(full_name):
'''Your function - just removed the other two columns.'''
    lst_rude_words = ['RUDEWORD', 'ANOTHERRUDEWORD', 'YOUGETTHEIDEA']
    full_name_with_offensive_word = any(item in full_name.upper().split(' ') for item in lst_rude_words)


%timeit df.apply(lambda x: func_in_list(x['full_name']), axis=1) #3.15 ms
%timeit df['full_name'].str.upper().str.contains(lst_rude_words_as_str, regex=True) #505 µs
```

**EDIT**

I added the other two columns that I'd left out before - here's the full code

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'full_name': ['Mickey Mouse', 'M Mouse', 'Mickey Rudeword Mouse']})
def df_metrics(input_df):
    input_df['full_name_less_than_2_parts'] = input_df['full_name'].str.split().map(len) < 2
    input_df['full_name_with_initial'] = input_df['full_name'].str.split(expand=True)[0].map(len) == 1
    lst_rude_words = ['RUDEWORD', 'ANOTHERRUDEWORD', 'YOUGETTHEIDEA']
    lst_rude_words_as_str = '|'.join(lst_rude_words)
    input_df['full_name_with_offensive_word'] = input_df['full_name'].str.upper().str.contains(lst_rude_words_as_str, regex=True)
    return input_df
```

***RESULTS***

For the 3 row dataset - there is no difference between the two functions -

```
%timeit df_metrics(df)
#3.5 ms Â± 67.7 Âµs per loop (mean Â± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df[['full_name_less_than_2_parts', 'full_name_with_initial', 'full_name_with_offensive_word']] = df.apply(lambda x: full_name_metrics(x['full_name']), axis=1)
#3.7 ms Â± 59.6 Âµs per loop (mean Â± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But when I increase the size of the dataframe - then there is some speed up

```
df_big = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

%timeit df_metrics(df_big)
#135 ms Â± 7.03 ms per loop (mean Â± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

 %timeit df_big[['full_name_less_than_2_parts', 'full_name_with_initial', 'full_name_with_offensive_word']] = df_big.apply(lambda x: full_name_metrics(x['full_name']), axis=1) 
#11.5 s Â± 173 ms per loop (mean Â± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer piecemeal...

All your ops rely on splitting the full name column on whitespace so do it once:

```
>>> stuff = df.full_name.str.split()
```

For name less than two parts:

```
>>> df['full_name_less_than_2_parts'] = stuff.agg(len) < 2
>>> df
               full_name    nationality  full_name_less_than_2_parts
0           Mickey Mouse      Mouseland                        False
1                M Mouse  United States                        False
2  Mickey RudeWord Mouse         Canada                        False
```

---

Name with only an initial.

Explode the, split, Series; find the items with length one; group by the index to consolidate the exploded Series and aggregate with `any`.

```
>>> q = (stuff.explode().agg(len) == 1)
>>> df['full_name_with_initial'] = q.groupby(q.index).agg('any')
>>> df
               full_name    nationality  full_name_less_than_2_parts  full_name_with_initial
0           Mickey Mouse      Mouseland                        False                   False
1                M Mouse  United States                        False                    True
2  Mickey RudeWord Mouse         Canada                        False                   False
```

---

Check for undesirable words.

Make a regular expression pattern from the undesireable words list and use it as an argument to the `.str.contains` method.

```
>>> rude_words =r'|'.join( ['RUDEWORD', 'ANOTHERRUDEWORD', 'YOUGETTHEIDEA'])
>>> df['rude'] = df.full_name.str.upper().str.contains(rude_words,regex=True)
>>> df
               full_name    nationality  full_name_less_than_2_parts  full_name_with_initial   rude
0           Mickey Mouse      Mouseland                        False                   False  False
1                M Mouse  United States                        False                    True  False
2  Mickey RudeWord Mouse         Canada                        False                   False   True
```

---

Put them yogether in a function (mainly to do a timing test) that returns three Series.

```
import pandas as pd
from timer import Timer
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "full_name": ["Mickey Mouse", "M Mouse", "Mickey RudeWord Mouse"]*8000,
        "nationality": ["Mouseland", "United States", "Canada"]*8000,
    }
)
rude_words = r'|'.join(['RUDEWORD', 'ANOTHERRUDEWORD', 'YOUGETTHEIDEA'])
def f(df):
    rude_words = r'|'.join(['RUDEWORD', 'ANOTHERRUDEWORD', 'YOUGETTHEIDEA'])
    stuff = df.full_name.str.split()
    s1 = stuff.agg(len) < 2
    stuff = (stuff.explode().agg(len) == 1)
    s2 = stuff.groupby(stuff.index).agg('any')
    s3 = df.full_name.str.upper().str.contains(rude_words,regex=True)
    return s1,s2,s3

t = Timer('f(df)','from __main__ import pd,df,f')
print(t.timeit(1))    # <--- 0.12 seconds on my computer
x,y,z = f(df)
df.loc[:,'full_name_less_than_2_parts'] = x
df.loc[:,'full_name_with_initial'] = y
df.loc[:,'rude'] = z
# print(df.head(100))
```

---

[Series Accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#accessors)

Comment: I have other tests not reliant on splitting btw if that makes a difference ```full_name_with_invalid_character_format = not(bool(re.match('^[a-zA-Z\s\-]+$',full_name)))```

So you think the timing issue might be to do with the splitting, I had thought the blame would mostly lie in testing against lists, obviously they are longer than 3 items.

Comment: Not necessarily the split. The improvement will be if you/I can figure out how to operate on the Series as a whole instead of applying operations row-wise.